# C error I've not encountered before

Tags: c, variables, pointers, integer

```
shell_command(char gcommand[100]) {
    FILE *pipe = popen("ls", "r");
    char output[100];

    if ( pipe ) {
        fgets(output, sizeof output, pipe);
        pclose(pipe);
    }
    return output;
}
```

results in

> program.c: In function ‘shell_command’: 
> program.c:42: warning: return
>   makes integer from pointer without a cast 
> program.c:42: warning:
>   function returns address of local variable

Ive googled around in two days with no success

Comment: Your function has no return value which apparently defaults to `int` as in pre-C99. Thus the first warning. The implicit-`int` should have given a warning before. For the second warning: See e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9013402/i-am-getting-warning-function-returns-address-of-local-variable-in-c) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12380758). And at least for the second warning I get a bunch of answers by searching for the message.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have declared your function as

```
shell_command(char gcommand[100])
```

which is interpreted by the compiler as

```
int shell_command(char gcommand[100])
```

while you want it to be

```
char* shell_command(char gcommand[100])
```

which would not work, because output is a stack variable and returning that is undefined behaviour, as your compiler tells you.

Answer (score 3):

1. You've not specified the return type of the function, so the compiler assumes it returns an `int`, but you're trying to return a `char *`. Note that pre-standard C and C89 allowed this 'implicit return type'.  C99 and beyond require the return type.  Compilers still allow the code through because of the pre-standard legacy code.
2. You're trying to return the local variable `output`, but that variable vanishes when the function returns. (You also return a pointer to an uninitialized variable if the `popen()` fails.  And you ignore the `gcommand` parameter that's passed to the function.)

You should probably pass the buffer and its size to the function:

```
int shell_command(const char *gcommand, char *buffer, size_t buflen)
{
    FILE *pipe = popen(gcommand, "r");

    if (pipe)
    {
        char *result = fgets(buffer, buflen, pipe);
        pclose(pipe);
        if (result != 0)
            return 0;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

This returns 0 on success and -1 on failure, and (now) checks the return value from `fgets()` which could fail, but ensures that the pipe is closed regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Another way than returning char*. You are returning a local pointer variable. Instead pass a character array and copy output variable into that array using strcpy()
Another method is to return character array and return type of function is char*

Comment: Modified with one more solution.