# How Does Variables Inside Functions Which are Removed From The Stack Behave in Memory

Tags: c, pointers, memory, memory-management

i wrote this block of code in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int* fun() {
    int x = 43;
    int* ret = &x;
    return ret;
}

int main() {
    int* r = fun();
    printf("%d", *r);
    return 0;
}
```

the original code was:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int* fun() {
    int x = 43;
    return &x;
}

int main() {
    int* r = fun();
    printf("%d", *r);
    return 0;
}
```

and i fixed the "Return Local Pointer" Warning by doing

```
int* ret = &x;
```

now my question is that in the first example the code prints 43 and i don't understand why ? shouldn't the pointer be a pointer to garbage value after the function "fun" executes and gets removed from the stack because the variable "x" is destroyed and it no longer holds the value 43 ? so why does dereferencing the pointer "r" after "fun" executes results in 43 ? why does this block of memory that held the variable "x" still not removed even after the function "fun" removed from the stack ?

Comment: `43` is as much garbage as `-7652342` or any other number :-)

Comment: It's undefined behavior. You're just lucky. Memory is protected on a page basis. It's still there, but might cause a segfault.

Comment: Stack memory is never `removed` - it's just made available (unchanged) for whatever it's need for next.

Comment: Technically, the memory location has been freed but nobody has written anything to it yet, so it still holds the previous value. But this is undefined behavior, you could get a totally different value under other circumstances.

Comment: [The result may change by turning on optimization](https://wandbox.org/permlink/zfHDkF0Hi5zyAQCG).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return address of local variable in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8743411/return-address-of-local-variable-in-c)

Comment: What if you print it twice? `printf("%d\n", *x); printf("%d\n", *x);`? Number 2 may shock you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is by chance. You are invoking *undefined behavior* for dereferencing a pointer pointing at an object whose lifetime is ended.

When I entered your code to [Compiler Explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Whd5qj83E), I got this:

```
fun:
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        movl    $43, -12(%rbp)
        leaq    -12(%rbp), %rax
        movq    %rax, -8(%rbp)
        movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
        popq    %rbp
        ret
.LC0:
        .string "%d"
main:
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        subq    $16, %rsp
        movl    $0, %eax
        call    fun
        movq    %rax, -8(%rbp)
        movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
        movl    (%rax), %eax
        movl    %eax, %esi
        movl    $.LC0, %edi
        movl    $0, %eax
        call    printf
        movl    $0, %eax
        leave
        ret
```

In this illustration, let me assume that `%rsp = 0x10000000` just before executing `call fun`.

`call` pushes the return address on the stack, so it will subtract 8 from the stack pointer. `push` also subtract 8 from the stack pointer. Therefore, when `movl    $43, -12(%rbp)` is executed, `%rbp` is `0x0ffffff0` and the layout on the stack is:

```
     -12(%rbp) -> 0x0fffffe4  43
                  0x0fffffe8  (the address to return will be written here)
                  0x0fffffec  (the address to return will be written here)
        (%rbp) -> 0x0ffffff0  old base pointer %rbp
                  0x0ffffff4  old base pointer %rbp
                  0x0ffffff8  address to return from fun
                  0x0ffffffc  address to return from fun
                  0x10000000
                  0x10000004
                  0x10000008  (returned address will be stored here in main())
                  0x1000000c  (returned address will be stored here in main())
%rbp in main() -> 0x10000010
```

After returning from `fun()`, there are no memory write that destroys the `43` written before reading the value by `movl    (%rax), %eax`. Therefore the value happened to be preserved.

Note again that you are invoking *undefined behavior*, so the result may differ.

For example, when `-O2` optimization option is added, Compiler Explorer gave me [this](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/o3hbKv1Ys):

```
fun:
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        ret
.LC0:
        .string "%d"
main:
        subq    $8, %rsp
        xorl    %esi, %esi
        movl    $.LC0, %edi
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        call    printf
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        addq    $8, %rsp
        ret
```

Now the buggy function `fun()` is replaced with empty process and the result is changed.