# Why I this address is being changed after initialization in main function? (C)

Tags: c

I'm new to C and I'm facing some problems with a project I am working on.

In vm.h

```
#define STACK_MAX 256
typedef double Value;

typedef struct {
   Value values[STACK_MAX];
   Value* top;
}

typedef struct {
   Chunk* chunk;
   uint8_t* ip; // Instruction pointer
   Stack stack;
} VM;

VM initVm();
void resetStack(Stack* stack);
```

In vm.c

```
void resetStack(Stack* stack) {
    stack->top = stack->values
}

VM initVM() {
    VM vm;
    resetStack(&vm.stack);
    return VM;
}
```

In main.c

```
int main() {
    VM vm = initVM();

    ... 
}
```

Ok, here's the problem. After I initialize vm, vm.stack.top is pointing to vm.stack.values[0] (which I don't know why is filled with garbage values instead of zeroes), but one instruction later, no matter what, vm.stack.top is changed and starts pointing something else or sometimes the address of the vm.stack.values[0] is changed to another.

[image: Here the top property is well pointed to the start of the array]

[image: After the return the pointer remains the same but the address of the first element of the array has changed]

Comment: With `stack` being a pointer, this cannot compile: `stack.top = stack.values;`. Please show real code that reproduces your problem. Not something made up.

Comment: `Stack *stack; stack.top` is incorrect.  You should use `->` instead of `.`.

Comment: Please create a proper [mre] to show us.

Comment: Why would you expect a variable to contain zeros?

Comment: Assuming your are actually doing something like `stack->top = stack->values` you assign the address of `values` member of local variable `Vm` which does not exist and longer after you return from `initVM`

Comment: Global variables are automatically initialized to zeroes, but local variables have no automatic initialization. So the array won't be zeroed.

Comment: It is legal to a struct as in `return VM;` but you're putting a lot of load on it, containing  an array as it does.

Comment: Instead of using a pointer for `top`, use an integer index.

Comment: Either that, or allocate `VM` dynamically, and return a pointer to it. Then the `top` pointer will remain valid.

Comment: @Gerhardh it returns the struct, not a pointer to it ;)

Comment: @WeatherVane the struct contains a pointer that is pointing to the array in the local variable. That is a pointer, too ;)

Comment: @Gerhardh yes it's messy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return address of local variable in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8743411/return-address-of-local-variable-in-c)

Comment: People should really stop `typedef`ing structs that are not opaque.

Comment: @Barmar it’s faster to dereference a pointer than look up an element in an array by index.

Comment: @Gerhardh yep, the problem was I was passing a local variable. Malloquing the vm and the freeing it, resolved the problem.

Comment: The performance difference is neglgible.

Comment: @Cheatah, Re "*People should really stop typedefing structs that are not opaque.*", huh? No thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem was VM was declared in the local scope. Allocating VM in the heap
solved it.