# Problem with passing between pointers of arrays in structures

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have been sitting on this problem for 3 hours and I would appreciate it if you could guide me,
We have the student structure that contains a name, and points to an array of pointers of size 3 only and it should point to 3 different teachers (random of course), when I try to return the pointer to the random array from teacherArray, within the operation AttemptTeacherToStudents, in practice, nothing is received, And the pointer remains empty.
I would really appreciate the help

My structs:

```c
typedef struct
{
    char name[20];
    struct ClassRoom * myClass;
}Teacher;

typedef struct {
    char * name;
    struct ClassRoom *myClassRoom;
    struct Teacher *myTeachers[3];
    
}Student;

int InitalizeStudent2(Student *student, char *name, Teacher *teacher)
{
    student->name= name;
    *student->myTeachers = teacher;
    printf("%s", name);

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is with this code:

```c
Teacher ** teacherArray(Teacher * teachers)
{
    Teacher *randomArray[3];
    int i = 0;
    while (i<3)
    {
        Teacher * teacher=teachers + (rnd() % 6);
        randomArray[i++] = teacher;

    }
    return randomArray;
}
void AttempTeacherToStudents(Teacher* teachers)
{
    Student * allOfMYStudents = (Student *)malloc(5 * sizeof(Student));
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        char name[255];
        sprintf(name, "Student_%d", 100 + i);
        char *newName = _strdup(name);
        InitalizeStudent2(&allOfMYStudents[i], newName, *teacherArray(teachers));
    }

}


Teacher** InitalizeGenrealTeacher()
{
    char allTeachers[6][6] = { "Teach1\0", "Tech2\0", "Tech3\0","Tech4\0", "Tech4\0", "Tech5\0" };
    Teacher * myTeachers =(Teacher*) calloc(6 , sizeof( Teacher));

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        InitalizeTeacher(&myTeachers[i], allTeachers[i]);
        

    }
    return myTeachers;
    
}


int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    Teacher*pMyTeacher = InitalizeGenrealTeacher();
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {

        printf("%s \n", pMyTeacher[i].name);
    }
    

    AttempTeacherToStudents(pMyTeacher);
}
```

[image]

the problem is, why the pointer of "myTeachers" is empty at [1][2]? why does cell number [0] not null too?

Comment: Please enable all compiler warnings. For GCC use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`.

Comment: `teacher = (rnd() % 6);` While picking 3 out of 6 it is rather likely to get duplicate results.

Comment: `return randomArray;` This should trigger some compiler warning. You return the address of a non-static local variable. Its lifetime ends after you return from that function. Any attempt to access the content of that array afterwards, is illegal.

Comment: Besides that, you do not show enough code. We don't see prototypes and implementations of the functions you call or how the shown function is called. Please read [How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question to include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return address of local variable in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8743411/return-address-of-local-variable-in-c)

Comment: Thanks for all comments, i edited my questions with all  the code

Comment: `"Teach1\0"` That does not fit into an array for 6 `char`s

Comment: `strcpy(student->name, name);` at this point `student->name` is uninitialized and so that's [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (ie. it will probably crash). You need to allocate memory to `student->name`. I'd recommend making Student and Teacher consistent whether `name` is stored as a pointer or an array.

Comment: Still not compileable. Still throwing lots of warnings. `return myTeachers;` You return `teacher*` while `teacher**` is expected. No idea if the hidden function `InitializeTeacher` does some ugly hack to make it look correct.

Comment: `*student->myTeachers = teacher;` That only assigns a single teacher (yes, that illegal address from earlier...) to the first element of the pointer array. All the other pointers stay uninitialized.

Comment: The program crashed on the InitalizeStudent2(), I dont know how to fix it, because im giving him an address of the array.. any suggestions?

Comment: As I wrote twice: That address is illegal to access. Check the question I linked. There you can read how to avoid returning local addresses.

Comment: I did some Changes, Please take a look :)

Comment: You ignored all my comments

Answer (score 0):

First, turn on compiler warnings. They will give you a lot of extra information and avoid a lot of frustration. How you do that depends on the compiler/IDE you're using.

---

```
int InitalizeStudent2(Student *student, char *name, Teacher *teacher)
{
    // student->name is uninitialized
    strcpy(student->name, name);

    // student->myTeachers is an existing array of 3 elements, yet you're assigning an existing array to it.
    // student->myTeachers is `struct Teacher*` which does not exist, it should be `Teacher*`
    *student->myTeachers = teacher;

    return 0;
}
```

`student->name` is defined as `char *name`. Unlike `char name[20]`, you need to allocate memory for the student's name. I would recommend using [`strdup`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/strdup) for that, and to make Teacher and Student consistent as to how they store strings.

`student->myTeachers` is declared as `struct Teacher *myTeachers[3]`. There is no `struct Teacher` only `Teacher`. `typedef struct { ... } Teacher` only declares `Teacher`.

`student->myTeachers` is allocates an array of 3 elements, yet you already have an allocated array of Teachers. If you're going to add an existing array to Student, declare it as `Teacher *myTeachers` to just store the pointer and assign it with `student->myTeachers = teacher`.

Note that the `teacher` passed to `InitalizeStudent2` is from `teacherArray` and has already been deallocated. Read on.

---

```
Teacher ** teacherArray(Teacher * teachers)
{
    // This will be deallocated when the program returns.
    Teacher *randomArray[3];
    int i = 0;
    while (i<3)
    {
        // I'm not sure what the rand() % 6 is for.
        Teacher *teacher = teachers + (rand() % 6);
        randomArray[i++] = teacher;

    }
    return randomArray;
}
```

`Teacher *randomArray[3]` allocates automatic memory. This memory will be deallocated once `teacherArray` returns; that means something can overwrite that memory. It's very convenient, but it means if you return it something might overwrite it. Instead, you need to allocate the memory with `malloc` or `calloc` and then `free` it later. Alternatively, the caller can allocate the array and pass it into `teacherArray`.

Otherwise, it's unclear what this function is trying to do.

---

```
Teacher** InitalizeGenrealTeacher()
{
    // It's not necessary to add the \0 to strings.
    // But do remember to allocate an extra byte for the \0.
    char allTeachers[6][6] = { "Teach1\0", "Tech2\0", "Tech3\0","Tech4\0", "Tech4\0", "Tech5\0" };

    // There's no need to cast calloc or malloc.
    Teacher * myTeachers = (Teacher*) calloc(6 , sizeof( Teacher));

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        InitalizeTeacher(&myTeachers[i], allTeachers[i]);
    }

    // The function returns `Teacher **` but myTeachers is `Teacher *`.
    return myTeachers;
}
```

While C strings are terminanted by a null byte, `""` adds the null byte for you; it's just `"Teach1"`. You do need to remember the null byte when allocating memory, so `"Teach1"` needs 6 bytes. Since these are fixed size strings, you can let the compiler figure it out with `char allTeachers[6][]`.

The function returns `Teacher **`, which would be an array of Teacher pointers. But `myTeachers` is a `Teacher *`, which is an array of Teacher structs.

`InitalizeTeacher` is missing from your code.

Comment: I made some changes.
Most of the warnings that the compiler gives me are simply incomprehensible to me..
When I DEBUG the program, I do get some value back from the teacherArray program, I would appreciate it if you could look at the picture in the question I edited

Comment: @Bubi "*the problem is, why the pointer of "myTeachers" is empty at [1][2]? why does cell number [0] not null too?*" If you're referring to that portion, that is explained in the answer and there are many problems. There is no `struct Teacher`, it is `Teacher`. `Teacher *myTeachers[3]` defines and allocates an array of 3 Teachers, but you're assigning a brand new array to that; you probably want just a pointer `Teacher *myTeachers;` to just store the array of Teachers. `teacherArray` returns memory that is deallocated. You have to fix all that and understand the warnings.

Comment: @Bubi You will probably get a value back from `teacherArray`, but the memory has already been deallocated. The program is free to overwrite the memory later. C eventually use that memory for something else. So while your array may be there now, there's no guarantee it will be there later.

Comment: I did a callloc array for the Teacher is it stil a wrong way?

Comment: @Bubi Maybe, I'd have to see your code. Please update your question, or post it as a Github Gist.